# Filter for specific string and include 2 following rows

Tags: amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm doing some diagnostics for our application by searching for some specific messages on cloudwatch. A downside to searching for errormessages is that only the rows that match the string get returned, and sometimes valuable information is also included in the rows that were logged right after the log that was returned.

Is there a method of querying for a row with a specific value, and have a range of logs before and/or after this row included in the result?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do this, but you can include the @logStream in the output, click on the hyperlink that is added to the search output, and examine the logs manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you can do this is to run another search without the filter, but restricting the time window to around the event that you found. At the moment, you cannot get the before/after log events through a single search.

Comment: That's a shame. Imagine I need to inspect a crash, the only way to check all logs leading up to this crash is to adjust the query time-window by time-window?